# How to split two array then merge in one? The best way using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to split data from BE and then sort by some prefix.

Example of array ->

```
  let dataFromBE = [
    {name: 'item one' , id: 1},
    {name: 'item two' , id: 2},
    {name: 'TEST:1' , id: 3},
    {name: 'TEST:1' , id: 4},
    {name: 'ASC item' , id: 5},
    {name: 'some item' , id: 6},
    {name: 'ASC item' , id: 6},
  ];
```

What I need ? To sort items with prefix 'TEST:' in first ( top ) array and sort other items alphabetically.

This is my way but maybe is not enough good

```
  const itemsWithPrefix = tags?.filter(
    (item) => item.name && item.name.toUpperCase().startsWith('TEST:')
  );

  const otherItems = tags?.filter(
    (item) => item.name && !item.name.toUpperCase().startsWith('TEST:')
  );

  let mergedArr: any[] = [];
  if (itemsWithPrefix && otherItems) {
    mergedArr = [...itemsWithPrefix, ...otherItems?.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1))];
  }
```

Is there a possibility for this to be done without creating two separate sequences, but only iteration through one? Thank you. And any other attempt to be more readable than mine is totally fine.

Comment: Use `sort` with a custom sort function that gives priority to "TEST".

Comment: Can you at least tell me in a little more detail how to do it?

Comment: `dataFromBE.sort((a,b) => b.name.startsWith("TEST:") - a.name.startsWith("TEST:")
|| a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`

Comment: [How to sort alphabetically an array of object depending on name and a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837748)

Comment: Please do not deface your question, especially one that has already been answered. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort()` with a custom sort function that gives priority to "TEST"

```js
let dataFromBE = [
    {name: 'item one' , id: 1},
    {name: 'item two' , id: 2},
    {name: 'TEST:1' , id: 3},
    {name: 'TEST:1' , id: 4},
    {name: 'ASC item' , id: 5},
    {name: 'some item' , id: 6},
    {name: 'ASC item' , id: 6},
  ];
  
dataFromBE.sort((a,b) => {
    const aIsTEST = a.name.toUpperCase().startsWith('TEST:');
    const bIsTEST = b.name.toUpperCase().startsWith('TEST:');
    if (aIsTEST && !bIsTEST) return -1;
    if (!aIsTEST && bIsTEST) return 1;
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(dataFromBE);
```

Comment: @Cinovates , the Above solution, looks fine. you are not doing exactly the same as in the second check I mean If condition as Johnny doing.

Answer (score 2):

you can use includes() method instead of comparison inorder to avoid exact matching

```js
let dataFromBE = [
    {name: 'item one' , id: 1},
    {name: 'TEST: ' , id: 2},
    {name: 'TEST:1' , id: 3},
    {name: 'TEST:2' , id: 4},
    {name: 'ASC item' , id: 5},
    {name: 'some item' , id: 6},
    {name: 'ASC item' , id: 6},
  ];
  dataFromBE.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a.name.includes("TEST:")  && !(b.name.includes("TEST:"))) return -1;
    if (!(a.name.includes("TEST:"))  && b.name.includes("TEST:")) return 1;
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
console.log(dataFromBE)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using sort

```
  let dataFromBE = [
   {name: 'item one' , id: 1},
   {name: 'item two' , id: 2},
   {name: 'TEST:1' , id: 3},
   {name: 'TEST:1' , id: 4},
   {name: 'ASC item' , id: 5},
   {name: 'some item' , id: 6},
   {name: 'ASC item' , id: 6},
    ];

dataFromBE.sort((a, b) => {
   const nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); 
   const nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
   if (nameA.startsWith("TEST") && !nameB.startsWith("TEST")) return -1;
   if (!nameA.startsWith("TEST") && nameB.startsWith("TEST")) return 1;

if (nameA < nameB) {
  return -1;
}
if (nameA > nameB) {
  return 1;
}
  return 0;
});
console.log(dataFromBE)
```